# RestApi server code is not workinng

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to write the `RestAPi` server code and I am badly stuck.

My directory structure is `/var/www/html/RestApi/rest/` file. I am writing the sever code in this folder. My .htaccess file is located at /var/www/html/.htaccess and files located Following is setting of my .`htaccess` file

```
/var/www/html/<br>
          |<br>
          |<br>
          |--- index.php, .htaccess<br>
          |<br>
          |---/RestApt/rest/api.php (restapi server code)<br>
              /RestApt/rest/ .... (Other files to support api.php)<br>
```

`.htaccess` looks like

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^/RestApt/rest/(.*)$ /RestApt/rest/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/RestApt/rest/(.*)$ /RestApt/rest/api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^/RestApt/rest/(.*)$ /RestApt/rest/api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Now in my api.php I have one api:

```
private function users(){
    // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
        $this->response('',406);
        }
        ...
    }
```

After having all this when I call RestApi from browser using chrome RestAPi extension i am getting following error

> The requested URL `/RestApi/rest/users` was not found on this server.

In my apache file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I already did following modification

```
AllowOverride All
```

I am really stuck, please throw some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the very first slash `/` from your rewrite rules. They should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^RestApt/rest/(.*)$
```

Also I've noted a possible misprint: RestAp**t**

Comment: No change still getting the same error. I modified the rules as following 

 RewriteRule ^RestApt/rest/(.*)$ RestApt/rest/api.php [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: And what's about the misprint?

Comment: Ohh I corrected that one... I guess the issue is where i should put my .htaccess file other thing can be which file i should enable AllowOverride

Comment: I tried lot of things but nothing helping me. Can you please tell me where i should put the .htaccess file in /var/www/html or /var/www/html/RestApi/rest/

Comment: You should put it to `/var/www/html`

Comment: I am placing the .htaccess at right location. This is the error in the error log of apache. <br> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2015:14:17:17 +0530] "GET /RestApi/rest/users HTTP/1.1" 404 450 "-" "curl/7.35.0" <br> when i give command "curl -v http://localhost:80/RestApi/rest/users"

Comment: I am using ubuntu machine and when i check abut 450 error code i saw "450 Blocked by Windows Parental Controls (Microsoft)"